# Converting formula to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

I am trying to build out a "How Much car can I afford" calculator that takes three arguments: Monthly Payment, interest Rate, and loan length. The three values are then calculated to present to user with a car value they can afford based off the data they entered. I was given then following formula:

```
CarValue = (MONTHLY PAYMENT * (1-(1+(INTEREST RATE / 12)) ^ -TERM)) / (RATE / 12)
```

using ECMAScript 5  I'm trying to convert this formula to JavaScript and its giving me wild results:

```
var monthlyPayment = $scope.model.howMuchCanIAfford.monthlyPayment;
var interestRate = $scope.model.howMuchCanIAfford.interestRate;
var loanLength = $scope.model.howMuchCanIAfford.loanLength;

var monthlyAmount = (monthlyPayment * (Math.pow(1-((1+(interestRate / 12))), (-1 * loanLength)))) / (interestRate / 12);
```

**Example Data:**

```
monthlyPayment = 700
interestRate = 9.2
loanLength = 84

output: $4,503,380,362,412.83
```

Obviously the output amount is wildly off and I'm unsure if my formula conversion is the issue or the original formula I was given is wrong.

Comment: You can use the formula as is in Javascript, just replace `^` with `**`... and make sure all the inputs are Numbers.

Comment: yeah im not using javascript 6 so i cant use **

Comment: think you just need to be careful about units…  presume interest rate is a proportion, i.e. if the user picks 9.2% you want to use 0.092

Comment: Consider the precedence of operators. Minus is evaluated after the exponent power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var monthlyAmount = (monthlyPayment * ( 1- Math.pow( (1+(interestRate / 12)), (-1 * loanLength) ))) / (interestRate / 12);
```

In the original formula the -1 is outside of parentheses that are raised to a power.

Comment: Are you sure? You are closing the bracket of the Math.pow function without the exponent

Comment: Right, I mixed up the brackets too. It should be correct now